# Openssl upgraded via apt-get, `openssl version` showing previous version

Tags: debian, package-management, upgrade, openssl

I am running Debian Wheezy. I have just upgraded my system and should have the latest version of openssl (1.0.1g which fixes a [critical bug](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt)), but it does not appear to be being used.

I have run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

dpkg -s openssl shows: `Version: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u5`

openssl version shows: `OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`

I have rebooted my system since upgrading. What do I need to do to get openssl using the updated version?

Comment: See also [How do I recover from the Heartbleed bug in OpenSSL?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123711/how-do-i-recover-from-the-heartbleed-bug-in-openssl) (which touches on this concern, but buried in a bigger answer).

Answer (score 9):

Per the Debian bug tracker, the Heartbleed issue was updated in version `1.0.1e-2+deb7u5`:

> Marked as fixed in versions 1.0.1e-2+deb7u5. Request was from Salvatore Bonaccorso  to control@bugs.debian.org. (Mon, 07 Apr 2014 21:45:14 GMT) Full text and rfc822 format available.

As such, you're running the updated version and are no longer vulnerable.

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/743883

This is common practice: Debian applied the security fix to the version that was already in the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So it's normal for the command
`openssl version` to still report the same as it was previously? I guess I expected that would change.

Comment: I agree that `openssl version` reporting the same as before isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: If you have doubts, you can check for the vulnerability using http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/

Comment: @user51279 run openssl version -b and you can see the updated build date.

Comment: Note that the "openssl" package only contains the tools etc. If you are looking for security fixes to the library you need to check the versions of the library packages (libssl1.0.0 and libcrypto1.0.0 )

Answer (score 2):

The upstream version is `1.0.1e`, which is what is being shown. What is the problem? Note the `2+deb7u5` after the dash is Debian-specific.

Comment: Because 1.0.1g is the latest upstream version at this time, and a lot of people are paying attention because of a [highly publicized security vulnerability](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123711/how-do-i-recover-from-the-heartbleed-bug-in-openssl). Debian followed their practice of backporting security fixes, which isn't immediately obvious to people who aren't used to this practice.